# Negative Definite Fano Manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, fano-varieties

A complex manifold $M$ is said to be **Fano** if the Chern curvature $2$-form is a positive definite $(1,1)$-form. What happens if the Chern curvature $2$-form is a negative definite $(1,1)$-form? What are such manifolds called, and do they differ in any meaningful way from Fano manifolds?

Comment: Usually they are called general type and complex hyperbolic manifolds are examples. They behave vastly differently from Fano varieties. For example Fano varieties have Kodaira dimension $-\infty$ whereas varieties of general type has maximal Kodaira dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such manifold are called of general type (at least in the projective case). If you look at *compact* Riemann surfaces, then the only Fano variety is $\mathbb{P}^1$ while curves of general type have bigger moduli spaces. Their geometry, and even topology, is really different.